# Trying to run my ml model on docker using flask api

Tags: docker

I am getting an error while trying to run my ml model API in docker container and it says

```
Error: ' ' is not a valid port number.
```

This is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.10

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app 

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD gunicorn --workers=4 --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app
```

and this is my app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

model=pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/predict", methods = ['POST'])
def predict():
        
    int_features=[int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final=[np.array(int_features)]
    prediction=model.predict(final)
    
    
    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Final report: {}'.format(prediction))




if __name__ == " __main__ ":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and if possible, please throw some light on **EXPOSE** and **CMD** keywords used in dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the value for `PORT` variable.

`ENV PORT=8080`